# How do I troubleshoot ssh tunnels disconnection?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd, syslog, troubleshooting

I am using SSH tunnels launched via autossh at boot on a device installed at remote locations. Up to now everything was working fine but yesterday the connection partly went down and autossh wouldn't do its thing. And I would love to figure out what happened to prevent it ever happening again. I have to deal with SLAs and all.

Here are the details:

***THE SETUP***

*Remote site:*

-Raspbian on a raspberry pi (debian wheezy)
-Autossh running at boot connects to our server and establishes 3 ssh tunnels
   Tunnel 1: regular tunnel forwarding a local port on the raspberry pi to a server in our office
   Tunnel 2: reverse tunnel opens a port on our server pointing to a device on the remote network
   Tunnel 3: reverse tunnel opens a port from our server's loopback (127.0.0.1) adapter pointing to the ssh port of the raspberry pi on its loopback adapter.

So basically with this setup I have to ssh in our server from which I can ssh into each remote devices.

*SSH Server:*

-Debian Wheezy
-No firewall/iptables on the server, we use another box for this

***THE PROBLEM***

Both reverse tunnels (tunnels 2 and 3) stopped working. The output of

```
sudo netstat -atp | grep ssh
```

Showed that the only port still opened was for tunnel # 1

When I killed the ssh process on the server for tunnel # 1 autossh did its thing and all tunnels were reconnected but I would prefer if I didn't have to do this.

Is it normal behavior for autossh? Does autossh have issues monitoring reverse tunnels?

*SYSLOG from the remote device*

```
Sep  7 06:25:06 remote_hostname rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="1661" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Sep  8 06:25:05 remote_hostname rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="1661" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
Sep  8 10:24:57 remote_hostname autossh[1428]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
Sep  8 10:24:57 remote_hostname autossh[1428]: starting ssh (count 2)
Sep  8 10:24:57 remote_hostname autossh[1428]: ssh child pid is 24161
Sep  8 16:53:53 remote_hostname autossh[1428]: ssh exited with error status 255; restarting ssh
Sep  8 16:53:53 remote_hostname autossh[1428]: starting ssh (count 3)
Sep  8 16:53:53 remote_hostname autossh[1428]: ssh child pid is 30541
Sep  9 06:25:05 remote_hostname rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="1661" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
```

Comment: Does it give more insight to run `ssh` with options `-v`, `-vv`, or `-vvv`?

Comment: Ha ha ha... I completely forgot that autossh is just a wrapper for ssh. I checked it's help dialog for debuging option and forgot to check ssh itself. Thank you!

Comment: So I'll make it an answer :)

Comment: Please do! My company just stopped supplying us with free coffee... I guess my ADD brain is having issues coping hehehe thanks again!

Comment: Ha, ask my brain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using various ways to create log output,
but do not mention the most important ones:

The command `ssh` itself has a "verbose" option `-v`.
And more interesting, it also has a "verry verbose" option `-vv`.
Oh, and "verry verry verbose", `-vvv`, which may actually be too verbose!

Does it give more insight to run ssh with options -v, -vv, or -vvv?

Showing how much verbosity the options enable:

```
$ ssh -v   localhost true |& wc -l 
56
$ ssh -vv  localhost true |& wc -l
122
$ ssh -vvv localhost true |& wc -l
282
```